# Считывание с экрана в Python с помощью OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Как с помощью OpenCV сделать считывание с экрана сразу в нескольких местах?

Ситуация такая: на экране появляются 3 изображения, известно их расположение и что очередность отображения случайна, то есть нужно пытаться считывать раз в секунду эти изображения и если там не белый фон, то переводить изображение в массив (NumPy).

Документация не особо помогла, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Google подсказывает ImageGrab модуль из pillow пакета можно использовать, чтобы участки экрана как numpy массивы получить и позже используя cv2 (opencv) обрабатывать.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Python : How to detect any changes in the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20580785/4279)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для захвата изображения с экрана можно использовать библиотеку [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot). Данная библиотека работает на всех операционных системах в отличии от PIL.ImageGrab.

Нужно воспользоваться методом `grab`. Данный метод в качестве входного параметра принимает координаты желаемой области, а затем возвращает изображение. Чтобы преобразовать изображение в массив numpy, достаточно воспользоваться вызовом `numpy.array`.

Вот так можно захватить три участка и преобразовать их в массив numpy:

```
import pyscreenshot as ps
import numpy as np

boxes = [(0, 0, 100, 100),
         (100, 100, 150, 150),
         (300, 300, 366, 350)]

arrays = []

for i in range(3):
    im = np.array(ps.grab(bbox=boxes[i]))
    arrays.append(np.array(im))

for array in arrays:
    print("Type:", type(array))
    print("dtype:", array.dtype)
    print("shape:", array.shape)
    print()
```