# Скриншот конкретного участка экрана Python

Tags: python, скриншот

Доброго времени суток.
Нужно сделать скриншот конкретного прямоугольника на экране, скорее всего, будет по координатам, и сохранить именно эту картинку. Весь экран не нужен. Координаты четырех точек и вся область между ними, наверное. Дальше для работы будет нужен только этот маленький прямоугольник. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Посмотрете ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573794/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-opencv/573853#573853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
if __name__ == "__main__":
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10,10,300,300)) # X1,Y1,X2,Y2
    im.show()
```