# Как распознать картинку на экране?

Tags: python

Допустим у меня на экране в определнном месте появилась картинка, как с помощью пайтона это определить?
Можете посоветовать книги\гайды\библиотеки?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Comment: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

Answer (score 1):

Выбор инструментов зависит от Вашей задачи.
Если точно известно расположение картинки и картинка всегда одна и та же (или ограниченное количество), то вам подойдет ответ на похожий вопрос: 
[Считывание с экрана в Python с помощью OpenCV](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573794/%D0%A1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-opencv)
В данном ответе используется библиотека pyscreenshot.
Тогда все сведется к сравнению списков.

Если картинка или местоположение динамическое, то посмотрите в сторону OpenCV.